# AppID not Detected

Tags: ios, facebook-login

I want login with facebook in Swift. They give me error AppId not set in Plist but I am setting AppId on plist. It gives this error:

> my2015-08-12 17:49:27.211 swiftcontact[16083:2102678] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason:
>   'App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key
>   FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:].'

These are the contents of my plist file:

```
<dict>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>9023XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.varun.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>BOOMaGIFT</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb9023XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this and what I did was declare my app id in the viewDidLoad just like this FBSDKSettings.setAppID("your_app_id").

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to add Facebook's ApplicationDelegate method inside my AppDelegate

```
ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(_:, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of **struggle** i am able to **solve** this issue.

In **react-native** if you are using **react-native-fbsdk-next** you will get the error on ios that App ID not found in info.plist file even if you already added in the file. It will work properly in **android** but not on **ios**.

To solve this issue make sure you have added facebook-app-id and app-secret in the info.plist and if issue is not resolved please add below lines of code in your **AppDelegate.mm** file --

Steps -

1. Open your AppDelegate.mm file in ios/project/AppDelegate.mm
2. find resturn YES
3. just before return YES paste the following line of code -

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

Remove the old app and install again it will work.
Reference link --
https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/96